# Select records by boolean column flag

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a table like this:

```
+----+--------------+-----------+------------+
| id | natural_id   | flag      | date       |
+----+--------------+-----------+------------+                                           
| 1  |           1  |  true     | 01/01/2000 |                                      
| 2  |           1  |  true     | 02/01/2000 |
| 3  |           1  |  false    | 03/01/2000 |
| 3  |           2  |  true     | 01/01/2000 |
| 4  |           2  |  false    | 02/01/2000 |
| 5  |           2  |  false    | 03/01/2000 |
+----+--------------+-----------+------------+
```

And I'm trying to write select, which will show records with **natural_id** and **date**, according to **first** **flag** false value:

```
+--------------+------------+
| natural_id   | date       | 
+--------------+------------+                                      
|           1  |  03/01/2000|                               
|           2  |  02/01/2000|
+---------------------------+
```

I have no idea how to do this in SQL. Is it even possible in pure SQL?

Comment: Totally possible. What version of mysql are you on?

Comment: It's not even related to any particular db. When you creating new question on SO, it requires to select at least 2 tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `group by natural_id`:

```
select 
  natural_id,
  min(date) date
from tablename
where flag = 'false'
group by natural_id
```

If flag's type is `BOOLEAN` you can do it like this:

```
select 
  natural_id,
  min(date) date
from tablename
where not flag
group by natural_id
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use correlated subquery :

```
select t.*
from table t
where t.id = (select t1.id
              from table t1
              where t1.natural_id = t.natural_id and t1.flag = 'false'
              order by t1.date
              limit 1
             );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT natural_id,date
FROM
(SELECT natural_id,date,flag, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY natural_id, 
       ORDER BY date ASC) AS RowNum
FROM table) A
WHERE RowNum =1 AND flag = 'false'
```